# Shadow but no object illumination effect in three.js

Tags: three.js

I would like to upload a mesh with color coded scientific data in three.js. It should result in a nice shape with a realistic shadow, but the object's color itself should not depend on the position relativ to the light (in particular the side facing the light source and its opposite) in order for the color to remain in accordance with the data scale.

Is there an object property that I can set to fulfill this requirement?
If not is there a different workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `MeshBasicMaterial()` http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshBasicMaterial which is not affected by the light.